# Why didnt work change class? and can cnahge class better?

Tags: jquery, class, addclass

Tell me please why my code doesn work?

```
$('.action').live('click',function(){
    var idn = this.id.split('+')[1];
    var id=$('#input'+idn);
    if(id.hasClass('class1')){id.removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');}
    else if(id.hasClass('class2')){id.removeClass('class2').addClass('class1');}
    });
```

Comment: 1. `.live()` is deprecated! 2. Does this work? `this.id.split('+')[1];` I am not sure. 3. Did you click the element with the class `action`?

Comment: 1. worked now,
2.worked
3. yes i use action with click on class 'action'
but code id.get(0).play(); worked
and my code  if (id.hasClass('class1'))  isnt work((

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted works fine: please see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy5p/)

Note, `live()` has been deprecated in favour of `on()` or `delegate()`, depending on your version of jQuery and you can reduce your code with the use of `toggleClass()`:

```
$('.action').live('click',function() {
    var idn = this.id.split('+')[1];
    var id = $('#input' + idn).toggleClass("class1 class2");
});
```

Comment: toggleClass it good but, whow i can use him if my code: 

    $('.action').live('click',function() {
    var idn = this.id.split('+')[1];
    var id = $('#input' + idn);
    var id2 = $('#player' + idn);
    if (id.hasClass('class1')) {
        id.removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');id2.get(0).play();
    }
    else if (id.hasClass('class2')) { 
        id.removeClass('class2').addClass('class1');id2.get(0).pause();
    }
    });

Comment: @user1639908 in that case `toggleClass` wouldnt work for you, as there is extra logic contained in each condition. However, the point remains that what you have should work. Try checking the console for JS errors.